# Data visualisation Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, charts

## I tried to use `googlecharts` gem.

But it works with google image charts, which is deprecated.
And not everything works as it should. Can you recommend me something more usefull for data visualisation in ruby?

Comment: Do you want to generate a specific chart? What you want to visualize depends on where someone could point you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something similar to Google Image Charts to display on a web page - [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) will be best choice.

If you want to get image file - you can use gnuplot.

Both of them have gems for ruby.